# How to add a foreign key to Google Data Studio Blend

Tags: foreign-keys, looker-studio

I have 3 tables and I want to get different data for a chart. First and second have a common key, second and third have a common key, but first and third does not.

EXAMPLE DATA:

**TABLE product data**

product ID

product category

**TABLE orders**

order ID

Product ID

sale price

**TABLE order logistics**

order ID

Client ID

Client's country

What I want to achieve is a graph that shows:
Sum of sale prices for all product in category "cars" bought by client from country "USA"

I know how to use filters and how to make graph, my problem is how to get my data together in one document.

I know that I can modify data and add lookups in Google Sheets but as my data has 100 000+ rows I am looking for a more efficient solution than vlookup between tables in Google Sheets.

So far I could Blend data only when common key was present.

Comment: **NOTE**: The [17 Feb 2022](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11521624#feb-17-2022) update to Google Data Studio included improvements to data blending with additional join options, thus this is possible in Google Data Studio....as stated in the first comment, specific details are required to provide a specific answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blend in Data Studio needs the same common keys for all data sources.
You need to do these joins in BigQuery.

Comment: **NOTE**: The [17 Feb 2022](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11521624#feb-17-2022) update to Google Data Studio included improvements to data blending with additional join options, thus this is possible in Google Data Studio....